# Validate mail from AWS with Linode

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mail-server, linode, amazon-workmail

I have to link a domain from linode to AWS to send emails; I should add this entry in my linode:

```
RecordType: MX
Hostname: elcor.com
Value: inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

but I don't see the value field in linode, I only see:

```
Mail Server , Preference, TTL, Subdomain
```

and the it appears as **Inconsistent**

[image]

I can send messages but not receive them, I have this error:

The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect , FAILED_PRECONDITION: connect error (111): Connection refused]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to setup an SMTP domain name to send emails.

Typically, the SMTP DNS provided by AWS (e.g. email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com) is enough to use along with SES credentials in your sending script.

Other than this, it is a good idea to create DKIM records when authorising the sending domain (AWS walks user through the process).